# How to present a dictionary list with ant design?

Tags: antd

I want to display a dictionary **in a nice way**. In standard HTML I would use DL tag. I didn't find an analog in ant.design yet.

Comment: Are you using React?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ant-design, you have to install `yarn add antd` or `npm install antd --save`

After, the easiest way for ant-design is adding the index.html(ex.For React)

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/antd

You can use these link.

```
<link type="stylesheet" href="paste the antd css from url">
```

And then, you will be use this.

Lastly, I recommend to you "min.css" file.

Comment: TY for explanation how to start using ant.design. However you didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ant.design, it doesn't mean that you can not use standard HTML tags, you can still use them.

For example, this will look nice:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <dl>
      <dt>Coffee</dt>
      <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
      <dt>Milk</dt>
      <dd>White cold drink</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

Comment: I want all my UI pieces have similar style. So I would avoid writing styles myself.